# Would it be good to create a wrapper class when using condition_variable?

Tags: c++, multithreading, condition-variable

I see a common pattern when using `condition_variable` to let one thread wait for another thread to finish some work:

1. Define a condition, a `mutex`, and a `condition_variable`:

```
bool workDone = false;
std::mutex mutex;
std::condition_variable cv;
```

2. In one thread, do some work. And when the work is done, update the condition under lock, and notify the `condition_variable`:

```
std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex);
workDone = true;
lock.unlock();
cv.notify_all();
```

3. In another thread that needs to wait the work to be done, create a lock and wait on the `condition_variable`:

```
std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex);
cv.wait(lock, []() { return workDone; });
```

In each of the 3 parts, we need multiple lines of code. We can create a class like below to wrap up above codes:

```
template<class T>
class CVWaiter
{
private:
    T m_val;
    std::mutex m_mutex;
    std::condition_variable m_cv;

public:
    Waiter(_In_ const T& val) : m_val(val)
    {
    }

    void Notify(_In_ std::function<void(T& val)> update)
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m_mutex);
        update(m_val);
        lock.unlock();
        m_cv.notify_all();
    }

    void Wait(_In_ std::function<bool(const T& val)> condition)
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m_mutex);
        m_cv.wait(lock, [this, condition]() { return condition(m_val); });
    }
};
```

With this class, the 3 parts on the top can be respectively written as:

`CVWaiter workDoneWaiter(false);`

`workDoneWaiter.Notify([](bool& val) { val = true; });`

`workDoneWaiter.Wait([](const bool& val) { return val; });`

Is it a correct way to implement the wrapper class? Is it a good practice to use the wrapper class for scenarios like this? Is there already anything that can achieve the same in a simpler way in STL?

Comment: Sounds like you're implementing a "mailbox" (i.e., a sort of a 1-deep queue.)

Comment: With `T`=`bool`, this is basically an `Event` from the Windows API; C++20 supples `std::atomic::wait` with similar semantics.

Comment: As asked, the question is opinion-based.  Considerations include costs of writing/debugging the wrapper (hopefully one-off), maintaining it in future (e.g. extending capability/usage).   These need to be compared with the cost/benefit of *using* the wrapper (e.g. how much code [and, more importantly, effort] is saved on each usage, how many times it needs to be used [e.g. a couple of times in a program versus being part of a library used by numerous programs], etc). Probably not worth the effort if only used once or twice, but maybe beneficial if it will be routinely reused many times.